# How to handle NullPointerException in Java

Tags: java

How to handle `NullPointerException` in Java? Please provide details so I can get rid of this problem

Comment: If you can't post some code, the question is too broad. One tip: Handle nullpointers by checking if the objects given to you are really valid.

Comment: You will need to provide some code here so that others can help you out with your specific problem. NullPointerExceptions are pretty common problems

Answer (score 24):

You should avoid NullPointerExceptions:

```
if(someObject != null) {
    someObject.doSomething();
} else {
    // do something other
}
```

Normally you should ensure that the objects which you use are not null.

You also can catch the NullPointerException and except using an if-condition.

```
try {
    someObject.doSomething();
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
    // do something other
}
```

Normally there is a bug in your code, when a NullPointerException occurs.

Answer (score 15):

```
try {
    // something stupid
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
    // probably don't bother doing clean up
} finally {
    // carry on as if nothing went wrong
}
```

Comment: Although really you should probably be looking into `// something stupid` to make it less stupid

Comment: +1 for the catch block comment ;-).

Comment: This is the long way anyway; just do `public static void main(String[] args) {try {/* your code */} catch(Exception e) {}}` and all the problems go away

Comment: This is funny, but someone might take it seriously.

Comment: why is this being upvoted? It's a rubbish answer

Comment: Perhaps because not everyone upvotes based on the scientific soundness and completeness of an answer. Rather, they vote based on answers that they find amusing and/or can relate to.

Comment: @Finbarr Those people are voting wrong then. I don't think the answer is that detrimental though; hopefully my first comment will dissuade people from actually doing it

Comment: Is it actually possible to vote wrong in a community based and democratic system? Surely people should vote based on how they feel, not how they think others will think of their vote.

Comment: @Finbarr It's not possible to vote in a way that's against the rules (as far as I know), but it's absolutely possible to vote incorrectly. If you upvote all answers you think are wrong and downvote all answers you think are right, you're voting incorrectly, but you won't be suspended for it. You should upvote answers you feel are helpful

Comment: The humor makes the answer memorable, much more so than yet another stern lecture from "Some Dude on the Internet" about why catching NPEs is bad style.  I've given enough stern lectures to interns about catching NPE who still do it for 6 more months anway, that I feel the humor approach is in fact, helpful, +1 :)

Comment: Well, not all answers are black and white (wrong or right). This answer contains elements of the correct answer, but wrapped up in an amusing fashion. Bit of a gray area with regards to the upvoting!

Answer (score 2):

You should really make yourself familiar with the concept of a variable being null. Checkout the API: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

Generally, try to do more research in advance.